# iOS Splashscreen not showing using Phonegapbuild

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, phonegap-build

I'm using ionic project then phonegap build to compile my app, everything works well but the splash screens.

This is my config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
</feature>

<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon src="icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40"/>
<icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80"/>
<icon src="icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50"/>
<icon src="icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100"/>
<icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="icon-57@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="icon-60@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180"/>
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76"/>
<icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152"/>
<icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29"/>
<icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58"/>
<icon src="icon-small@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="87" height="87"/>

<gap:splash src="splash.png" />

<!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
<gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPhone 6 -->
<gap:splash src="Default-667h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1242" height="2208" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2208" height="1242" />

<!-- iPad -->
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

<!-- Retina iPad -->
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />

<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

I have the splashscreen images at the root directory, have any idea? i know that phonegap has been having a lot of changes recently so i'm a little bit lost of how to add correctly the splash screens.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you install the plugin? cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen?